# JQuery Mobile 1.4 - widgets appears OK on Page, but without skin on Popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

(It will be a self-answered question, I've spent lot of time with it, maybe someone else has not to do so.)

When I put my slider widgets to a page (`data-role="page"`), they work, but when I put the same HTML cose in a popup (`data-role="popup"`) div, JQM does not add the classes and listeners, they remain untouched, standard HTML5 widget.

```
<label for="width">Width:</label>
<input type="number" data-type="range" id="width" name="width" min="1" max="4" value="1" >
```

I am using following code to initialize popups:

```
$("div[data-role='popup']").popup();
```

Then I use this for opening:

```
$("#mypopup").popup("open");
```

The popup opens, with correct skin and position etc., but widgets remains untouched by JQM.

Answer (score 1):

First, I've tried a hack: I put the widgets inside a hidden `<div>` and a placeholder `<div>` into the popup, and I've copied the content of the hidden one into the placeholder. That worked only, when the page, which the hidden `<div>` resides already showed up. Also, there were a problem with it: the popup's position was determined in its "empty" state, so when I added widgets, the position has not adjusted to it, the popup window seems placed below the normal.

Finally, I've found what's missing. Popups should be initialized the following way:

```
$("div[data-role='popup']").popup().trigger("create");
```

The situation is that "create" trigger applies on pages when they show up, but not on popups, even they're located inside a page.

Comment: If the popup is located within a data-role="page" div at the same level as header/footer/content, it should work. If it is external to a page, call $("div[data-role='popup']").enhanceWithin().popup(). In 1.4 you can use enhanceWithin instead of trigger("create").